# Has anyone done Drag and drop multi-upload functionality for attachments/files?

Tags: visualforce, attachment, upload, jquery

I'm trying to create a visualforce page where someone can drag and drop attachments to upload them and they can see a preview of attachments that they have already uploaded.

There are a ton of jquery plugins that do this ([one of the better ones](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/#)) but I was wondering if anyone has already done this in visualforce or has a recommendation for which plugin/library to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, It's pretty difficult, as you need to be able to `base64encode` the file before it's sent to the server (this can accomplish in *some browsers* Firefox, Chrome, Safari? Probably not IE.)

Also, to get VisualForce to properly encode the 'form-data' that is being submitted to the server you need to create a VF form that points directly to a 'File Input' field, which is hard to link to a drag and drop functionality. So I recommend doing something like:

```
<iframe src="myvfpage_with_file_input_form" style="display:none; />
```

And have your parent page fill in and submit the form on the hidden vf page in the form when the drag and drop takes place.

I like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) for drag & drop, it uses Flash/Javascript (free version) and/or HTML5/Javascript (in the paid version).

Comment: Does Uploadify work well with Visualforce?

Answer (score 4):

There is a product on the AppExchange that does this already.[Drag and Drop Attachments](https://sites.secure.force.com/appexchange/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008ZVcdEAG&d=70130000000sUh3&RRID=123456789)

Answer (score 1):

[@Kenji776](https://twitter.com/#!/search/users/kenji776) built a really slick javascript drag-and-drop file upload interface for a cloudspokes challenge, but got stuck by the fact that apex:inputFile doesn't support multiple files. If you want to take a look, [here's the submission video](http://www.screencast.com/users/CloudSpokes/folders/Default/media/ea4cef0f-acbb-4d0d-87d8-06717cf12e52) and here's [the idea on ideaexchange](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000ZV8hAAG) to vote for if you'd like to throw your support behind the request to add support for multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

TehNrd had a post on multi file uploads: http://www.tehnrd.com/multi-file-uploader-for-salesforce-oh-ya-and-progress-bars-too/

It doesn't include drag and drop. I would imagine you might be able to take parts of his code and add the drag/drop functionality on top of it.

Comment: I actually saw that but since I need both preview and drag & drop it seems like it would be easier to port an existing jquery library that does this.